# How do I write a link that works for a specific youtube channel video?

Tags: anchor, apple-mail

When I add a link which contains a `#` hash tag, Apple Mail 3.6 on the Mac OS X does not link it properly.

This: **http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance#p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0**

Becomes: **http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance#p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0**

Would really appreciate some help.

Regards
Craig

Comment: What email client are you using? You should just be able to add a hyperlink in the body of your email.  This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate this isn't a programming question but thought you gals/guys would be able to answer it easily. i'm using mac mail version 3.6 (936). Craig

Comment: http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/How_to_Insert_a_Link_in_an_Email_with_Mac_OS_X_Mail.htm

Comment: yes, you are awesome for giving this a go! checked out about.com and unfortunately, found nothing new. this is the video i want to link to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdf2Z0vpnT0 it links fine from email this one http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance#p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0 causes an error. anything else up your sleeve? Craig

Comment: i gather it has something to do with the anchor...

Comment: Works fine for me, are you sure that when you create the hyperlink you are putting in the entire URL as above, including http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance#p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0?

Comment: yep, entire url entered. when i click on the above links they both work a treat. the prob is when this one http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance#p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0   is added to an email (error- 404 not found, and interestingly this url appears http://www.youtube.com/user/chromeperformance%23p/u/1/fdf2Z0vpnT0 notice the %23 inplace of the #). if you try it from your email program you'll see what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Mail has a bug which doesn't allow you to use the hash `#` sign in a URL. If you go to `Edit > Link > Add` in Apple Mail and paste the url into it, it won't let you.

Unfortunately through testing and scouring the web, a solution does not exist, though many complain.

The best alternative is to use a URL shortening service such as http://bit.ly to produce a short url which can then be added to an email.

Comment: wohoo! thanks a million... it's a terrific fix...all the best, Craig

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Also, if you're looking for an alternative email client, **Mozilla Thunderbird** is very good, and FREE. It's brought to you by the folks who created Firefox. **http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/**

Comment: i appreciate that you gals/guys are programmers and this sort of question isn't really within your charter. suffice it to say, 'you rock!'